# I can't uninstall nodejs

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, installation, uninstall, node.js

I had an external hard drive that I used to program on both, the notebook and in the PC. There I had installed my Nodejs. Whenever I needed to code I opened the HD. However, my HD broke, and I lost everything that was there. So I tried to install nodejs on my notebook. But it appears as if it was already installed, and that it cannot find to uninstall.

[image]

I already tried to update by cmd with a "cup nodejs", but it returns:

> nodejs v14.3.0 [Approved] nodejs package files upgrade completed. Performing other installation steps. The upgrade of nodejs was successful. Software install location not explicitly set, could be in package or default install location if installer.
>
> Chocolatey upgraded 1/2 packages. 1 packages failed. See the log for details (C: \ ProgramData \ chocolatey \ logs \ chocolatey.log).
>
> Failures - nodejs.install (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C: \ ProgramData \ chocolatey \ lib \ nodejs.install \ tools \ chocolateyInstall.ps1'. See log for details. "

I also tried to go to the programs directly in the file to delete all the installation folders of nodejs. But even after it is deleted, when I click on the installer the same message appears.

It seems that even though it was installed on the external hard drive, it stayed on the notebook as if it had been installed on it. Now I can't uninstall or update, much less install another one, because the message that the drive is invalid is always displayed.

Comment: Windows usually keeps settings of the installed applications in [registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) - that's why it's failing in installing; try something like CCleaner to help you remove the remaining files & registry entries

Comment: tks, ill try it.